# Laravel 8 - Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel8.brand' doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've been searching the web for quite a long time and I have tried adding the `protected $table = "brands";` to my Brand Model as seen here:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Brand extends Model
{
    protected $table = "brands";
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'brand_name',
        'brand_image'
    ];
}
```

Then on my controller I have the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Brand;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class BrandController extends Controller
{
    public function AllBrand(){
        $brands = Brand::latest()->paginate(2);
        return view('admin.brand.index', compact('brands'));
    }

    public function StoreBrand(Request $request){
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'brand_name' => 'required|unique:brand|min:4',
            'brand_image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        ],
        [
            'brand_name.required' => 'Please input brand name',
            'brand_image.min' => 'Brand longer than 4 Characters'
        ]);

        $brand_image = $request->file('brand_image');
        $name_gen = hexdec(uniqid());
        $img_ext = strtolower($brand_image->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $img_name = $name_gen.'.'.$img_ext;
        $upload_location = 'images/brand/';
        $publish_image =  $upload_location.$img_name;
        $brand_image->move($upload_location,$img_name);

        Brand::insert([
            'brand_name' => $request->brand_name,
            'brand_image' => $publish_image,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);

        return Redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Brand added successfully!');
    }
}
```

Passing this through my routes:

```
// For Brand Route
Route::get('/brand/all', [BrandController::class, 'AllBrand'])->name('all.brand');

Route::post('/brand/add', [BrandController::class, 'StoreBrand'])->name('store.brand');
```

Which I also used on my form inside `views/admin/brand folder`:

```
<form action="{{ route('store.brand') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
  <input type="text" name="brand_name" placeholder="Brand name"/>
  @error('brand_name')
  <span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"> {{ $message }}</span>
  @enderror
```

My database table is named `brands` but adding `protected $table = "brands";` did not solve this. I even tried to re-migrate and do this all over again but nothing seems to work at all.

Are there anymore ways to solve this issue? I keep on getting the `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel8.brand' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from` brand`where`brand_name `= Bx LLC)` error whenever I am adding a new brand.

Please help!

Comment: in validation you need to put the table name so `brands` with an `s`. not the model, or put the whole model namespace `App\Models\Brand`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is not in storing Brand, but in validation:

in your validation:

```
'brand_name' => 'required|unique:brand|min:4',
```

this told Laravel to make sure of brand name uniqueness in 'brand' table, so when the query committed, you see that error.

this validation should be:

```
'brand_name' => 'required|unique:brands|min:4',
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of specifying the table name directly, you may specify the Eloquent model which should be used to determine the table name:

```
  'brand_name' => 'required|unique:App\Models\Brand|min:4',
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique